# Is it OK to put semantic information in the HTTP reason-phrase in a REST API?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

For example, I might want to return the current sequence number of the resource with a 409 response to a HEAD request to a versioned resource, but I may not supply it in the response entity because HEAD doesn't allow any. Another example: suppose a POST request to a commit endpoint fails due to version conflict. I can respond with 409, but sometimes I may want to additionally inform the client that the transaction it was committing has exceeded the maximum retry count and further attempts will not be successful. I might return e.g. `HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict/final` instead of just `HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict` in this case. My question is, is this acceptable practice? HTTP 1.1 RFC does not supply a clear-cut answer to this question.

I know I can put such information in a `X-...` HTTP header, or include this information in the response entity in some manner (additional XML tag or JSON property etc.) Assume I can't or don't want to do so if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason phrase is cute for debugging; but that's it. It's gone in HTTP/2, and may be lost by intermediaries and/or software libraries; don't rely on it being preserved.

Answer (score -1):

The format of the HTTP response is

> Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF

As per the spec,Here Reason Phrase can be custom. You can add your version of the error message.Please check here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html. It mentions that

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

Comment: RFC's what I read first. I take 'local equivalents' to mean a German server saying "404 Nicht Gefunden" instead of "404 Not Found". It's not clear whether I may put semantic information there or whether it's a good idea.

Comment: Please don't cite RFC 2616 anymore.

Comment: @JulianReschke Sincere question: What should we be looking at instead of RFC 2616?  (I landed on this page with the same question as the OP, also having read RFC 2616 before I got here.)

Comment: @JonSchneider: the RFCs that obsoleted it: RFC 7230...5.